# Почему, если я выполняю регулярное выражение по принципу "ИЛИ" , то у меня оно срабатывает, хотя по отдельности не должно срабатывать?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть 2 регулярных выражения
`^\+?3?8?(0\d{9})`   - на проверку телефона и 9 символов.
`\b[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}\b)`  на проверку email

Если же я объединяю их и ввожу телефон длиннее чем 9 символов(либо опционально +38 и 9 символов), то регулярное выражение проходит, но по моей логике- не должно проходить.

Вот объединённое выражение

```
 /(^\+?3?8?(0\d{9}))|(\b[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}\b)$/
```

Comment: Установите ограничение на начло `^` и конец строки `$`, нужен ключ `m`. Обычно `или` помещают в группы, сделать группу без захвата можно так `(?:`. Для примера: https://regex101.com/r/GrQaT2/1

Comment: `^(?:(?:\+38)?0\d{9}|[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})$`, `m` тут не надо. Надо правильно группировать шаблоны.